# Read/Write plist on iPhone iOS 5

Tags: ios5, plist

I am studying iPhone development and facing a problem with a reading/writing plist file. I followed an example from a iPhone development book but keep getting an error message when running.

The error message says : 2012-04-26 00:21:09.759 FileHandling[5915:207] -[__NSCFDictionary addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x685ac40

Here is the example code (it seems fine to me...though):

```
NSString *plistFileName = [[self documentPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Apps.plist"];
NSLog(@"Where is the file? => %@", plistFileName);

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistFileName]) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFileName];

    for (NSString *category in dict) {
        NSLog(@"%@", category);
        NSLog(@"=========");

        NSArray *titles = [dict valueForKey:category];

        for (NSString *title in titles) {
            NSLog(@"%@", title);
        }
    }
} else {
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Apps" ofType: @"plist"];       
    NSLog(@"%@", plistPath);
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];
    NSLog(@"Let's take a look : %@", dict); 
    NSMutableDictionary *copyOfDict = [dict mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"Let's look at the mutable dictationary : %@", copyOfDict);
    NSArray *categoriesArray = [[copyOfDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];

    for (NSString *cateogry in categoriesArray) {
        NSArray *titles = [dict valueForKey: cateogry];
        NSMutableArray *mutableTitles = [titles mutableCopy];

        [mutableTitles addObject: @"New App Title"];

        [copyOfDict setObject: mutableTitles forKey:cateogry];
    }

    NSString *fileName = [[self documentPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Apps.plist"];
    [copyOfDict writeToFile: fileName atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, the problem is occurring in the call to `addObject:` on an `__NSCFDictionary`. This means that, at runtime, a dictionary received a message to add an object.

However, in this code snippet, `addObject:` is apparently being sent to an `NSMutableArray`. This probably means that each object `titles` you're retrieving from `dict` in the last for-loop is not an array, but in fact another dictionary, that your code is simply referring to as an array.

Indeed, your code does seem well-formed, so check the well-formedness of your source plist; open it up in a plain text editor. Also, you use a *ton* of logging, so confirm this way: in the output, dictionaries (including the root entry) are denoted by `{curly = braces}`, where arrays are denoted by `(round parentheses)`.